# "Sender address rejected" error in Evolution

Tags: 12.10, evolution, email

I get this error when trying to send emails. It receives emails just fine, the reported error was:

```
RCPT TO "RECEIVER" failed: "SENDER": Sender address rejected: not logged in".
```

*Where "RECEIVER" is the mail address I'm trying to send and "SENDER" is my email address.*

Please do not tell me i should just use thunderbird. I realize i can just use thunderbird i want to know how to make it work in evolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It gives you a good clue right there: you didn't configure evolution to log in before trying to send the mail. In the account settings for the relevant account, under "Sending Email", make sure you tick the "server requires authentication" box and fill in a username.